# SXA Component in partial design is not editable in page

Tags: sxa

Extending reference Question :[Does SXA support page specific content with Partial Design?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/does-sxa-support-page-specific-content-with-partial-design)

I have added a navigation and page content in partial design.
The page content is having page content and some other inherited information rendered using rendering variants.

As I have a common design, I am trying to have a common design, but the page content fields are not editable in page.

Please let me know, if any one have any work around or any sitecore settings with which, I can edit the components from partial design in page.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/does-sxa-support-page-specific-content-with-partial-design

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change **content** exposed by renderings placed on partial design but **not renderings** by itself.

The reason for that is fact that those renderings definitions are stored in partial design, not page. During runtime, they are just copied to the page presentation and bound with proper context item. So this is a bit different behavior than presentation inheritance via Standard Values in vanilla Sitecore. So if you would like to change something per page you would have to copy a whole presentation from partial, edit it and then not use partial anymore

This is how it works and this is expected behavior. The question is why would you want to use partial designs and change renderings at the same time (if you want to have 'common design').

If you describe your case I could help you with some "hacks".

Comment: Thanks for the response @Alan. 
In general: lets say I put a page content component in partial design and using the page design in my page. Now in exp editor, I am not able to edit the page content, I need to go back to content editor, make changes. 
All the components used in partial design and page design are not editable in exp editor.
I am very new to sitecore and SXA, let me know, if I am doing anything wrong or you have any work around !

Comment: Like I said this is expected behaviour. You will not be able to edit components but only content rendered by those components (for example `Content` field of your page)