# Get the content from third party API

Tags: sxa, api

We have requirement to create a dynamic Pages in SXA. This dynamic page will have a template. These template will have a page design with partial designs. All of the partial designs get the content from third party api.

The ask is

1. Currently we have one API which provides all the content for the page, how can we use the content to different partial designs?
2. We need to anchor link few sections on the page. So how we can provide flexibility to content authors to control the anchor links on the page. Anchor links component will part of the page design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities, depending on other requirements you can pick the best:

- the same **template**, different **Page Designs** - you can treat Page Designs as configuration items - provide default value for your page template by [assigning one page design](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/create-and-assign-a-page-design-in-the-content-editor.html#assign-a-page-design) and then let content authors to set different via Page Design field on a page
- different **template**, with it's own **Page Design** - you can predefine all Page Designs and [assign them](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/create-and-assign-a-page-design-in-the-content-editor.html#assign-a-page-design) to templates - you have the same number of Page Designs and templates - I suggest using one base template when you crate them to not duplicate fields.
- [page branch](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/101/sitecore-experience-accelerator/use-a-page-branch.html) - combination of two above - I like this the most (when you want to keep everything on partial designs). You can create predefined pages with components and even expose you component configurations to authors, so they can potentially change URL. While creating Page branch this article might be helpful - [page specific content with Partial Design](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/does-sxa-support-page-specific-content-with-partial-design)

Comment: Thanks Alan, Page branch approach did work well.